# MyRide, Carpooling website, built on older version, need help running it, TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, django-views

File "C:\Users\tabis\MY-RIDE\Carpool\urls.py", line 27, in 
url(r'^%s(?P.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'),
File "C:\Users\tabis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls_*init*_.py", line 22, in url
return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
File "C:\Users\tabis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import app
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import notifications.urls
from os import path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include('smuggler.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^broadcast/', include('broadcast.urls')),
    url(r'^$', app.views.IndexView.as_view()),
    url('^inbox/notifications/', include(notifications.urls, namespace='notifications')),
    url('', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),


]

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'),
            'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),)

# urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Uh, `'django.views.static.serve'` is not a callable (It is a string) so... In fact I see you configure the media urls after that correctly why don't you simply remove that?

Comment: okay, i  have removed that but now this error shows up: ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns' from 'django.conf.urls' @AbdulAzizBarkat